# Sagemaker charge from ListBucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

Looking at the breakdown of charges from AWS Sagemaker, I noticed only about 30% of total cost is from actually running the instances, surprisingly **~50 percent** come from S3 (shows as ListBucket) and 20% for other overhead. I wonder if there is a way to decrease this massive extra charge from S3.

To give more background, I run hundreds of training jobs each roughly 3 hours long, and the data is hundreds of pickle files zipped into a tar.gz file of size ~10G (gets unzipped in the instance).
So If I run 1000 jobs on instances with pricing $0.1/hr, I expect to see around $300 charge (1000 jobs * 3 hours * $0.1), however it ends up being close to $1000 with around $500 coming from "ListBucket"!!
I wonder where this comes from, since the s3 folder with training data is simply a single zipped file, why would ListBucket cost so much?

Comment: Is the S3 bucket in the same region as SageMaker instances? Hard to believe that ListBucket is costing that much - 1,000 list API requests cost $0.005. That would equate to 100m list requests, I think.

Comment: Yes they are in the same region (us-east-1). The cost shows up as ListBucket under API Operation. Very strange, what could sagemake do under the hood that could cause this..

Comment: What are the parameters of the training job ? That might give us an idea what is happening under the hood.

Comment: It's mostly the default parameters, but here are the things that seem more relevant: using small instance type (ml.m5.large), own docker container built on top of python:3.6, region is us-east-1 for training, image and S3 data, 30G attached volume, has experiment/trial config attached.